The itsadug/plot_diff and itsadug/plot_smooth produce inconsistent results for Generalized additive mixed effect models (GAMMs)
I have a GAM model for time series pupil size data for responses to differently oriented face images, labelled as: 0, 300 and 60 (all as factor levels, representing head orientations/views). data is collected from ~60 subjects, so I added subjects as random effect. view predictor refers to these 3 different head orientations, I wanted to model pupil responses over time for 3 different views.
I quickly formulated the model as follows,
model_view <- bam(pupil ~
s(timestamp, k=150) +                            
s(timestamp, view, bs = "sz", k=150) +       
s(subject_id, bs = "re", k=60),                      
data = merge_pupil, discrete = TRUE, nthreads = 15)

This might not be the most optimal model for my data, but I have a problem that is consistent in another dataset/ model; I am interested in smooth differences between two levels for example, 0 and 60; 60 and 300 ; 0 and 300.
First, this is how I plot the summed effects;
itsadug::plot_smooth(model_view, view="timestamp", plot_all=c("view"), rm.ranef=T, sim.ci = T,
main = "Pupil Response by Face View",ylab = "Predicted Pupil Area (in a.u.)",
n.grid = length(unique(merge_pupil$timestamp)),
hide.label = F, legend_plot_all = "topright",
col = c("firebrick2", "dodgerblue3", "green4"),
lwd = 3, shade= T,
v0 = c(0))


Next, I plot smooth differences as follows (for example, differences between 60 and 300);
plot_diff(model_view, view="timestamp", rm.ranef=T , comp=list(view=c("60", "300")), 
sim.ci = T,se=2.58, main="60 vs 300",mark.diff = T, ylab = "Difference in pupil 
dilation (a.u.)", n.grid = length(unique(merge_pupil$timestamp)), hide.label = F)

which produces the second plot here:

in the plot_diff descprition, sim.ci parameter is explained as follows;
"Using simultaneous confidence intervals or not (default set to FALSE). The implementation of simultaneous CIs follows Gavin Simpson's blog of December 15, 2016: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/. This interval is calculated from simulations based. Please specify a seed (e.g., set.seed(123)) for reproducable results. Note: in contrast with Gavin Simpson's code, here the Bayesian posterior covariance matrix of the parameters is uncertainty corrected (unconditional=TRUE) to reflect the uncertainty on the estimation of smoothness parameters."
My problem is: in plot_diff output, differences between two levels seem significant from ~1500 ms. However, confidence intervals in the first plot are very much overlapping in this time window, so it should be not significant.
As I mentioned, I have a similar problem in another model/dataset, so I am concerned that I misunderstand how these functions are working, or doing something wrong.
Tl;dr: plot_diff shows significant differences despite it is likely not.

Welcome to CV, Ahsen. I don't see a question here--only a statement.  And the statement seems predicated on some kind of interpretation of overlapping confidence intervals, but what is that interpretation??

hi, thanks for your comment! plot_diff is supposed to reveal if differences between conditions were significantly different from 0, and it's basically checking if the confidence intervals of smooth differences exclude 0. That's why I am comparing it to the CI overlaps in the first plot. If they are very much overlapping in model prediction , how does plot_diff result in huge significance?  I am mainly interested in answering if pupil response significantly differs between 2 conditions.

Please take a look at some of our posts about overlapping confidence intervals, because I suspect they might help you understand this situation.

More specifically this answer provides a good summary: requiring non-overlapping 95% CIs is akin to the difference being significant at an $\alpha$ on the order of 0.5% rather than 5% (for a t-test at least).
